# logging to a remote storage using log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a use case where Log4J2 needs to be used to log to a file on a remote storage (windows/Linux)

I looked through documentation online and haven't found anything relevant.
Currently not sure if this is even possible using Log4J2

Any idea if this is supported in Log4J2?

Comment: How would you like to log remotely? Log4j2 supports a plethora of network logging protocols from the basic SocketAppender to JMS to SMTP. But you need to send data _somewhere_ - so what’s receiving the remote data?

Comment: SocketAppender might be what you are looking for: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender